# Configure Moshi for Room TypeConverter

Tags: android, android-room, moshi

Given that I'm already using **Moshi** to convert the **Retrofit** response from JSON String to Objects, can I also configure the **Room Database** on Android to use **Moshi** for TypeConverter instead of manually typing up the TypeConverter functions and referencing **Moshi**?

Example of some code that I have been writing that I think seems redundant.

```
@TypeConverter
    fun fromJsonToPictures(value: String): List<PictureObject>? {

        val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
        val type = Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, PictureObject::class.java)
        val adapter = moshi.adapter<List<PictureObject>>(type)
        return adapter.fromJson(value)
    }
```

Comment: I faced a similar case recently and I couldn't find a simpler/cleaner way to do it :(